# How to take a catch in Ashes Cricket 2009?

Tags: ashes-cricket-2009

I'm using an Xbox 360 Controller for Windows to play Ashes Cricket 2009. I figured out the controls except that I don't understand how to take a catch.

Let's say I'm on the fielding side. When the ball is in the air and a fielder running to take the catch, the camera moves behind the fielder, a circle is drawn around the ball, and "E" is shown on the screen. This means that pressing <kbd>E</kbd> on keyboard would take the catch (I didn't try it though). But I don't understand what I should press on the Xbox controller. I tried several buttons, but couldn't figure it out.

Anyone knows how to take the catch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"E" means Enter, so press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to catch.

You should also know that there's a specific time you should press it. You'll see a circle higlighting the ball in three different colors: Red, orange and green.

If you press when it's **red**, you'll definitely drop the catch. If it is **orange**, you may or may not catch. If it's **green**, this is the right time to press enter to win the catch!

Answer (score 0):

Press the "A" button on your Xbox 360 controller to take a catch when the timing is ok..